# Can't see a class in the same namespace in different file at compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

My problem is as follows:

I have a namespace, let's say "Foo".  There are already two classes in it, let's say "MyClass" and "SomeOtherClass".  They are both in separate files.

I need to add a third class to this namespace, let's say "Data", in a third file.

To begin with I implemented the logic of "SomeOtherClass" without a problem.
But then the project evolved a bit and, for the sake of clarity, the logic within "SomeOtherClass" that was using "Data" needed to be moved into "MyClass".

But now whenever I try to compile I get a compiler error reporting that "The type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found".

What's strange is that if I try to type "Data" in the editor then intellisense prompts me with the valid options for that class, and it is the same if I start with "Foo.Data", the name is also display with the light blue color.

If I delete "Data" and add the class in the same file as "MyClass" everything is fine.  If I re-add "Data" in its own file (without deleting the one in MyClass' file) then I have an ambiguity between "Foo.Data" and "Foo.Data" (and this is logical).

I've also tried to delete and recreate "Data" from scratch, but it didn't solve anything.

I've searched on the internet for a solution, but I could only find answers relating to project references or Target Framework being bad, but this does not apply in my case, since they are all in the same project and I can access "Data" in others projects lying around.

NB: I don't know if it's important, but "MyClass" and "SomeOtherClass" inherit from the same parent class.

**1. MyClass.cs**

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private Data data; //Error at compile time - Type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found
    }
}
```

**2. Data.cs**

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Data
    {
        //Some logic to handle the data
    }
}
```

**3. SomeOtherClass.cs**

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class SomeOtherClass
    {
        private Data data; //Actually works well
    }
}
```

Comment: all class are in same project ?

Comment: Can you confirm relevant _*.cs_ files have _BuildAction_ set to _Compile_?

Comment: Yes, all class are in the same projet, under the same folder.

@Grx70 That one of the first thing I've check, and yes, all the relevant *.cs have BuildAction set to Compile

Comment: That's peculiar. From what you've posted (as vague as it is) it doesn't seem that this error comes from your code, so my next guess would be a "bug" in the project. I'd try the following steps: move `Data` to some other file (e.g. _Data2.cs) and delete _Data.cs_. If it helps, try to rename _Data2.cs_ to _Data.cs_. If it breaks again, inspect _.csproj_ file for references to _Data.cs_ and look for something unusual. If however moving `Data` to _Data2.cs_ does not help, the error might lie in your code after all - carefully inspect both `MyClass` and `SomeOtherClass`.

Comment: Also, I assume you've already tried "turning it off and on again", i.e. cleaning the project/solution, deleting _bin_ and _obj_ folders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, following @Grx70 advice, I've tried to rename many things.

Data, to Data2, with no effect. MyClass to MyClass2, with some effects.

By going throught the output given with the last change, I've found out that another project use the file MyClass.cs, and have a copy for all others files that are used in MyClass.cs.

By adding an Include in the csproj of this project for Data.cs, and copy/paste Data.cs file into its folder, it solved the problem.